# Getting dynamic values from an object

Tags: django

In the save of one of my django models I'm using django-dirtyfields to get all the fields that have changed. They don't store the new values though so what I do is grab all the dirty fields  (changed fields) into a list named dirty_fields. I then save the object and then try to grab all the values of the new fields to what they have changed to. How come what I have does not work? I get 'object has no attribute 'field'

```
new_values = ['{0}: {1}'.format(field,self.field) for field in dirty_fields]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirty_fields` will be a dictionary of changed fields. eg

```
{'boolean': True, 'characters': 'testing'}
```

When you iterate using `for field in dirty_fields`, `field` refers to the dictionary key, eg `'boolean'` and `'characters'`.  You cannot use `self.field` because this will attempt an attribute lookup name `field` on your instance.

Instead, you need to take the `field` key value, and ask that this field be looked up on the instance of self using [getattr()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

Try this:

```
new_values = ['{0}: {1}'.format(field, getattr(self, field)) for field in dirty_fields]
```